# Making customized .dict file for sphinx-4

Tags: java, dictionary, sphinx4

I am trying to make a Java application for live speech alphabet recognition by using Sphinx-4. I will only need the program to recognize a small number of words (i.e, the English alphabet).

I have managed to get the program running using the LiveSpeechRecognition and en-us dictionary. However, it is very slow and inaccurate (~50 x audio time). I am looking into making my own customized .dict file in hope of it running faster and more accurate.

May i ask whether that will work? If so, how can i make my own customized dictionary? If not, how can i improve the speed of the program?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a custom dictionary, but rather a custom [JSGF grammar](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/sphinx4:jsgfsupport). In order to represent single letters you can use `<letter>.` form, for example:

```
grammar letters;
public <letters> = a. | b. | c.;
```